# Replacing a word in a file with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I was trying to replace one string in a file. For example:

```
$PASSWORD="oldpassword"
```

with:

```
$PASSWORD="newpassword"
```

Here is the Ansible task which should do this:

```
- name: change password with lineinfile 
  lineinfile:
    dest: test.txt
    regexp: '^$PASSWORD='
    line: '^$PASSWORD="newpassword"'
    state: present
    backrefs: yes
```

Unfortunately I can't find the reason why it isn't working. I cannot replace it with the new string.

I was also trying without `backrefs` and the string was added instead of replaced.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

From [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> $: Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of
>   the string

So, escape `$` with backslash.

```
  - lineinfile:
      dest: /tmp/test.txt
      regexp: '^\$PASSWORD='
      line: '$PASSWORD="newpassword"'
      state: present
```

Also you don't need to use the `backrefs` parameter with your example, because your regular expression doesn't have backreferences.